# Инфинитив в роли подлежащего

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, члены-предложения, подлежащее

**У нас в Липягах раздобыть наживку не такое уж лёгкое дело**(Крутилин).

Объясните, почему тут подлежащее — ***раздобыть***? А тогда слово ***дело*** — какой член предложения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Грамматическая основа: **раздобыть не легкое дело.** Или: раздобыть — это не легкое дело. **Связка всегда относится к сказуемому**, что можно использовать для проверки.

Раздобыть — подлежащее, не легкое дело — сказуемое (связанное сочетание).

**Это оценочный тип отношений**: предмет и его оценка (в качестве предмета может использоваться инфинитив). В этом случае мы однозначно определяем подлежащее и сказуемое даже при инверсии: Не легкое дело — раздобыть наживку.

**Другие примеры с оценкой:** Курить — здоровью вредить. Славные люди соседи мои (инверсия). Соседи мои — славные люди (без инверсии).

2) Другой тип предложений связан **с отождествлением**, например: Наш долг — (это) учиться. Учиться — (это) наш долг. Здесь подлежащее и сказуемое определяется по позиции (подлежащее на первом месте).

Comment: Хотел бы уточнить. Словосочетание - не легкое дело является цельным, потому что имеет значение качественной оценки?

Comment: Здесь основное лексическое значение словосочетания заключено в определении. Сравнить: Нелегко - раздобыть наживку.